# Mapping table name in Entity, when you define Code-First by existing Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, many-to-many, relationship

I already have defined my Database, and now I'm doing Code-First, creating the Objects so they fit with the current database.

My only problem is that the mapping table names dont entirely aggree with me.

My primary table is "Movies". Then I have a many-to-many to "Actors", and another many-to-many to "Genres".

My problem is >
  The mapping table name for Actors is totally fine.. Entity aggrees with "MovieActors", BUT! The Genre table, Entity wants to call "GenreMovies".

Why does entity want this? And how can I force it to use "MovieGenres"?

Please let in mind that I have already created the Database, and dont want entity to create any tables.

Comment: Try overriding `ModelCreating` in your `DbContext` class and map entity class to table to avoid this kind of collisions.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I suspect that this is not an option because MovieGenres is not an entity. Jonatan - have you tried reverse engineering the database? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620

Answer (score 0):

If your class is named `Genre`, by convention Code First presumes this will map to a table named `Genres`. If that's not the case, you can specify the name of the table with the [Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn) attribute. Here for example, the annotation is specifying that the table name is `GenreMovies`.

```
[Table("GenreMovies")] 
public class Genre
```

Another option is use [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx). The easiest way is overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in your Context:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().ToTable("GenreMovies");
 }
```

If you want to change the name of that Table in DB, I suggest you learn how to use [Code First Migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)